# Creating an object with data that changes depending on time

Tags: java, time, statistics

I have created an object to store a lot of data.

There are a total of 15 different types of this objects, for which I need to store data with the following time frame:

```
8.00 9.00 10.00 11.00 12.00 //ect ect
```

an example of this would be: in between 8.00 - 9.00 the data of this type would be 15 and between 9.00 and 10.00 it would be 5.

Now when I want to calculate the average of these numbers I want to get the average of each time period so for example I wish to find the average of the data between 8.00 and 9.00

My question is not how to get the data, but instead how I would store the data in my object.

So far my object looks like this:

```
    public class CallQueue {

    private String type;
    private int data;

    public CallQueue(String type, int data){
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;   
    }
    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

My question to you is: What is the best way to store an `Integer` with a timestamp ? I'd prefer to avoid `Hashmap` or `Hashtable` since they are harder to loop through! Can I avoid this in some way and if, so how?

**Update - More information**

My goal is to use the following method (this is in my statistic class)

```
public void calculateAverage(double time){
        if (time != 20.00) {
        double data =0; 
        int times = 0;
        for (CallQueue cq : getData()) {
            data += cq.getData();
            times++;
        }       
        averageData.add(data/times);
        calculateAverage(time + 1);
        }
    }
```

as you can see I want to add the average of the data between 8 - 19.00 (with interval of 1 hour) all of these will be added to an arrayList (`averageData`)!

So the `for each loop` needs to get all the data from each object at the given time

Comment: Depends very much on what you want to accomplish with the data.

Comment: @TheBlastOne i want to calculate the average of each timeframe (8 - 9, 9 - 10 ect) and add that average to a graph

Comment: Did you thought about using Databases? you could easily do it with databases.

Comment: @MukulGoel i am getting all the data from the database. but do you think i should calculate the average before creating the object instead of after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My question to you is: What is the best way to store an Integer with a timestamp ?**

I would say.

Create a class with two members

> a integer
>   a date

That is the way I could think of. If there exists anything better. Not sure.

Comment: This would require me to create 15 * 12 different objects to get all information

Comment: @MarcRasmussen ,hmmm.. then I guess.. creating a hashMap is your best bet. And trust me.. it aint that hard to navigate through it